# Migrate MSSQL TDE from certificate to EKM

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption, hsm

We have a handful of MSSQL databases encrypted using Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) without an HSM.
So the current chain is:

Service Master Key (SMK) ->
  Master Key (DMK) ->
   Certificate encrypted by DMK ->
    User Database - Data Encryption Key (DEK)

The databases are encrypted using the same certificate. Is there a possible migration path to utilizing an HSM without having to re-encrypt all of the databases?
(there is around 100TB of data, so I am trying to avoid re-encryption if at all possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to an HSM key very easily by simply re-encrypting the DEK using an asymmetric key from the HSM:

I won't get into all the details of setting up an HSM, except for the final two items:

First, make sure you have your HSM asymmetric key set up:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY TDE_KEY
    FROM PROVIDER AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov WITH
    PROVIDER_KEY_NAME = 'MySQLRSAKey', -- The name of the asymmetric key in Azure Key Vault
    CREATION_DISPOSITION = OPEN_EXISTING -- To indicate that this is an existing key in Azure Key Vault
```

Second, re-encrypt your DEK with the asymmetric key you just set up:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
ALTER DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY ENCRYPTION BY SERVER ASYMMETRIC KEY TDE_KEY
```

That's it!
If you ever have to switch back to non-HSM mode (i.e. a certificate):

```
USE [MyDatabase]
ALTER DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE MyEncryptionCertificate
```